# Geometry to Latitude/Longitude in Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, geometry, spatial, geography

I've uploaded `.SHP` files to my table in sql and I got geometry column with data. I can see points on **"Spatial results"** tab in sql server and that's all fine. When I run this line in sql server

```
SELECT [geom].STAsText() FROM myTable
```

I get these kind of results

```
POLYGON ((3176400.1697998047 13775644.29901123,... ))
MULTIPOLYGON ((3176400.1697998047 13775644.29901123,... ))
```

Also

```
select U.Region_Name, Centroid.STY as Longitude, Centroid.STX as Latidude from 
  ( select geom.STCentroid() as Centroid, NAME as Region_Name from dbo.special )
```

gives

```
Longitude Latidude 13752659.4654854 3187156.41156205
```

So is there any way to convert this to regular latitude and 
longitude (Eg. `34.403823, -118.596661`).

Comment: use this site: http://prj2epsg.org/search and tell us the format your shape file is in. Without that information we cannot help you because we don't know what those points are based off of.

Comment: Does you shp file include a prj file?

Comment: Your data looks to be in EPSG:3857, but it is impossible to be sure without more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the geometry by doing:

```sql
select geom.STSrid
```

With that being said, I don't think it's possible to convert coordinates between different SRIDs in SQL Server (or at least not easy without external libs (see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2723/is-it-possible-to-reproject-spatial-data-using-sql-server)), which i'm guessing you're trying to do here, so you might need to get it manually converted in another program before importing